# angular 2 master-detail share observable for update

Tags: angular

In the Angular2 example ToH, The master component retrieves data via web API. The hero.service returns an observable.

And the detail component also retrieves data via web API by id.

I see observable as immutable client storage. If I update a hero in the detail component I would push the change to the observable first and then when the user hit save button I would post the updated observable (to json) to the api server.

I am thinking the benefit is to reduce IO traffic and keep master and detail in sync (I updated the detail and it would automatically reflected in the master).

hero.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {Hero} from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  private _heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/api/hero/';  // URL to web api
  private _cachedHeroes;

  constructor (private http: Http) {}      

  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
      if (!this._cachedHeroes) {
          this._cachedHeroes = this.http.get(this._heroesUrl+"readAll")
                                        .map(this.extractData)
                                        .catch(this.handleError);
       }
       return this._cachedHeroes.share();
  }

  getHero (_id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.http.get(this._heroesUrl+"read/"+_id.toString())
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  addHero (name: string): Observable<Hero>  {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ name });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this._heroesUrl, body, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  private extractData(res: Response) {
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
      throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body.data);
    return body || { };
  }


  private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

In the above I cached the master data into _cachedHeroes as observable. So my question are that

1. Is it a good idea to let master and detail component share the same observable data?
2. If yes, in getHero (_id: number): Observable< Hero >, instead of making a api call,  how can I get a detail object out of the _cachedHeroes by id?
3. And after updating the detail or adding a new detail object how do I put the updated/new detail back into _cachedHeroes?
4. And when I want to save how do I know which object(s) in _cachedHeroes I should send to the database?

Any recommended/best practice for this kind of issue?

Comment: You could create a `Subject` in your service and pass it as an `Observable` to your components. Then you could submit your changes/new objects to your service, take care of the persistence there and emit the updated version of your data. If you are interested in global state management I would suggest looking into [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [Redux for Angular](https://github.com/angular-redux/store) specifically